# Identifying piece of circuitry on a PCB

Tags: pcb, components

I haven't done electronics for a long time but am doing some for a hobby project this weekend. I'm looking for some help breaking down/analyzing a circuit board I want to modify/hack:

[image: Board Photograph]

It's for 3 lights (designated by R, Y and G on the board). At the moment it lights each in turn and I'd like to be able to light one at a time by ignoring/circuventing whatever timer/control mechanism is being used right now.

- The black wire in R goes to each light's -ve terminal
- The black wire on the left and the brown wire on the left are -ve and +ve respectively
- I've identified the resistors, but would be curious to know why they're all different, when do you need to use different resistances and why is each blue one different when they each go to an identical light.
- I also identified the transistors - **TO-92/S8550/D331** apparently? I'm pretty sure these are for controlling whether or not the light should be on?
- Ceramic Capacitors **(p104)**, **not sure why we need these?**
- Tiny thing between the ceramic capacitors - not resistor. What this is?
- The upright board which takes +ve and -ve voltage, has a connection to each transistor as well as to C4, then the two rightmost connections seem to join together via resistor RC. ****What is going on here?****

I'm sure this is all really basic stuff so hopefully an electronics aficionado can fill me in :)

Thanks in advance!

****Update****

Wow - Thanks for all the input so far. The transistors have `S8550 D331` on them and a small circular indent on the curved side?

My plan was to follow all the circuit paths and create a schematic anyway and it seems that would help so I will go ahead and do that. Not sure how to model the IC chip though?

Also, I've added a shot of the underside of the board below (flipped so it mathches the same orientation/perspective) - seems pretty crappy, with solder even in places without components so I tried to colour them out to avoid confusion. If you open the image in a new tab/dowload both this and the previous one are high res by the way, might be easier to see!

If anyone beats me to a schematic (I imagine if you try you'll be much quicker) do share as I'd love to compare my attempt when I've had a go!

[image: Board Front and Back]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chip on Blob board, From left to right, on the top:

1. Ground, unconnected
2. V+
3. Green Led (Off when Logic High) (1kΩ resistor to PNP Base)
4. Yellow Led (Off when Logic High)(1kΩ resistor to PNP Base)
5. Red Led (Off when Logic High)   (1kΩ resistor to PNP Base)
6. Regulated Ground
7. Unknown, Connected to Pin 8 with a resistor, probably a mode select or delay based on the resistance.
8. See 7.

The capacitors are bypass 0.1uf capacitors, simply to filter out some noise on the power supply, standard value on nearly everything.

The Transistors are PNP transistors. Collector to the LED/Resistor/Ground, Emitter to V+. They are on when the base is logic low (ground), and off when the base is logic high (v+).

To use it with an arduino, you would simply remove the CoB board, connect a digital/pwm pin to 3, 4 and 5, as well as connecting the ground of the board and the arduino together. Since you would have it in output only, there isn't any issue with the V+ voltage level.

Answer (score 4):

> I've identified the resistors, but would be curious to know why they're all different,

If the lights are LEDs, different coloured LEDs can have different voltage drops so need different resistors to provide similar currents (and/or similar brightness)

> I also identified the transistors

TO-92 is just the case style. The devices will have an identifying number printed on the flat face. The photo lacks enough detail to see. I'd guess they provide current to the lights, perhaps the controlling IC (on the riser) can't provide sufficient current by itself. So yes, they're being used as switches.

> Ceramic Capacitors

Because of their position, they may be part of the power supply?

> Tiny thing between the ceramic capacitors

A diode. The ZD marking suggests a Zener Diode used for voltage regulation.

> The upright board

Looks like a chip-on-board. There's a tiny silicon IC under the blob.

If you posted a photo of the tracks on the underside of the main board, it might help show how the devices are interconnected.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I've posted an update with the board underside, any good?

Comment: @Peter: The extra photo helps a lot, I see Passerby posted an excellent answer during the night in my part of the world :-) See the [S8550 datasheet](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/WINGS/S8550.pdf)  - looks like a fairly boring PNP BJT.

Comment: Yeah, apparently so. Wasn't expecting anything interesting though given how basic the hardware is! I marked his as the solution because it's a nice explanation of the different IC connections which was the one I was most unsure about but your is a great answer too! All of this project is going in a blog post so I'll post back here when I'm done :)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick It was night in my part of the world too ;D

Answer (score 3):

I won't repeat much of the info already posted.  But here's some more experience-based analysis:

R5/6/7, are said to control the LED brightness (by limiting the current).  This is supported by two more observations.  One is that they are in series with each lead that goes to its LED.  The other is their low values.  R5=51 ohms, R6=22 ohms, and R7=27 ohms.   Assuming they stuck to the convention of NPN transistors and a common-emitter setup, these resistors will lead you right to the collectors of the transistors.

Next, we look at R2/3/4.  They are all 1K.  This is a common "can't really lose" value for connecting a drive signal to the base of a transistor.  So the next thing we get is that following the right side of each resistor will identify the base of each transistor.   More on this, in a moment.

Finally, there are outlines for more parts that are not installed.  DB107 would have been a rectifier bridge, and C1 and C3, filter caps for that supply.  Then the board would have run from an AC input.  The Zener diode suggests the AC voltage only had to be in some range (like 6 to 9 volts).

You can find out what the circuit runs from by powering it up and measuring the voltage at the Zener.  Identifying ground is left as an exercise to the student.

Lastly, if you power up the board and watch the voltage at the left side of R2/3/4, you will then know how that IC controls the lights.  Next, unsolder those same ends, and you now have a place to put your PIC/Arduino/555/IBM370 or whatever you're planning to control the lights from.

Comment: Great, thanks. I figured soldering to the left of R2,3,4 was the way to go! I am indeed planning on using a Raspberry Pi or Arduino. Will edit in a link back here with my finished project when it's done :)

I still felt asking the question was valuable though as I wanted to know how everything actually worked, not just hack in something blindly and cross my fingers!

Comment: @Gbarry with the added picture of the bottom of the board and the transistor part S8550, they are pnp, with the led/resistor/ground on the collector and v+ on the emitter.

Comment: Well, so much for "conventional".  At least it's still a common-emitter setup, with the LED's on the collectors.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit is built round the IC on the vertical board, under the black blob. It has weak drive outputs, so the transistors are used to drive the lights. The different resistors are probably to tune the apparent intensity of the different colours.

ZD between the capacitors is a zener diode acting as a voltage regulator. The capacitors are decoupling capacitors,  required for digital logic. There is spaceon the board for a diode bridge rectifier, which would allow ot to operate from AC.

RC is presumably a configuration or a time constant.

Answer (score 0):

Without a schematic of the board, not all of your questions can be answered.  However, I will take a shot:
      If the R,Y and G refers to different colored LEDs, then the resistors are probably different because each LED requires a different current to operate properly.
       TO-92 is the package type of the transistors and does not identify the transistor itself. What markings are on the transistors?  The transistor type for this kind of application is not critical but they must at least be established as being NPN or PNP.
      The ceramic capacitors are for timing and/or bypassing. If the board lights each lamp in turn, than that implies some kind of timing circuit.  Capacitors are usually used as one component, usually along with a resistor, to set a time constant to control timing.
       The thing between the capacitors is a zener diode (denoted by ZD on the board).
      Without a schematic it is difficult to determine how the board operates but the transistors may be connected as a multivibrator, with the RC's controlling the timing, so as to light the lamps in sequence.
       You should attempt to create a schematic by following the board traces.  Then we can see how to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Will try and create a schematic. I also just updated my question to include the board reverse if that's any good? As for what I'm trying to acheieve, I don't want to modify this question now I've asked it but I might ask another further down the line regarding how to actually make the changes I want :)

Answer (score 0):

The blinking behavior of the LEDs is most likely controlled by that little integrated circuit based daughter board. The transistors, and passive components just provide the current sourcing interface between that IC and the LEDs.

If you want a different behavior, desolder that IC and provide your own circuit to drive the lines. Figure out which inputs on that connector drive what transistors, which ones provide power and ground to the chip and off you go.